# Wordpress After Updating Avada Theme; Top Menu has disappeared

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have updated Wordpress Avada theme in my website. After updating I found the top menu has disappeared.
It's has appeared in dashboard but not in font end. Please kindly give me solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, dou you have any plugin to disable the frontend menu? Please check it.

If not, please deactivate and activate the Avada Theme and try it again.

When these both solutions not working please enable WP_DEBUG in wp_config like so:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

Please check if there is any error in the frontend after you refresh the page.

Comment: Hi Shinox, Thank you for your reply. I followed your steps and i got error **Notice: Constant WP_MEMORY_LIMIT already defined in /home/mfmediaipu/www/sivic/wp-si-vic/wp-config.php on line 93**

Comment: Please add ** define(‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ‘1024M’) ** maybe it will help. Or you will searching for WP_MEMORY_LIMIT in your wp-config file. Maybe there are two WP_MEMORY_LIMITs